# Deleting complete record in File 1 when a string from file 2 is found

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have one file which has data:

```
ID Name
1  abc
2  def
....
```

I have another file which has the strings:

```
ID
1
9
10
...
```

I want to search the data file with strings in the string file(having just ID) and if the string is found in the data file then delete ONLY that Record.

So in the above example:

Only the record with ID=1 should get deleted from the data file.

This has to be done on a unix system.

I have tried this:

```
grep -v -F /path/to/string/file/string.txt /path/to/data/file/data.csv
```

This lists out the content but does not edit/delete the record in the data file.

Thanks

Comment: That has been answered many times on SO. Did you try anything?

Comment: Sorry but I dont think I got the correct Answer. Please share the link where you think my question is answered and I will try that. This is what i have tried:


grep -v -F /path/to/string/file/string.txt /path/to/data/file/data.csv

Comment: you're expected to show your code in the body of your Q, not in comments. Please use 4 spaces at the front of each line that should be code or data to get the correct formatting. You're also expected to show that you did some research on your problem. If what you find is confusing or doesn't work for your case **then** you should post a well organized Q. Before posting further questions, please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Good luck.

Comment: Edited the question. Hope this is good now. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{keep[$1]; next} !($1 in keep)' string.txt data.csv
2  def
```

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Comment: Thank You for your help.
I executed this:    

awk 'NR==FNR{keep[$1]; next} !($1 in keep)' /path/to/string/file/string.txt /path/to/data/file/data.csv

But it does not edit the data.csv. It actually lists out all the content of data.csv.

Comment: Thank You for helping me here. Yes it does work if the file is same.
I would say it does solve my problem to some extent.
But if the data.csv has anything after the ID then it does not recognize those records.
Example:

    ID,Name

    1,abc

Then because there is a ,abc that record is not identified and hence not deleted.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention presence of commas in input. In that case use: `awk -F '[, ]' 'NR==FNR{keep[$1]; next} !($1 in keep)' string.txt data.csv > _tmp.csv && mv _tmp.csv data.csv`

Comment: Thank You Anubhava.
This trick helped.
Yes the question did not have presence of commas as I was solely focusing on the string and not the separator.
But your last suggestion worked. Mucho Gracias!!!!

Last thing: Can I have multiple separator list comma/pipe? If so How?

Thanks

Comment: Using `-F` argument you can add other delimiters e.g. `-F '[|, ]'` will use pipe, comma or space as delimiter. Do read about awk in given link above.